# API design for functions acting on arrays

Tags: java, api-design

I'm designing an API in Java for a set of numerical algorithms that act on arrays of doubles (for real-time financial statistics as it happens). For performance reasons the API has to work with primitive arrays, so `List<Double>` and suchlike are not an option.

A typical use case might be an algorithm object that takes two input arrays, and returns an output-array that contains a result computed from the two inputs.

I'd like to establish consistent conventions for how the array parameters are used in the API, in particular:

- Should I include an offsets with all functions so users can act on parts of a larger array e.g `someFunction(double[] input, int inputOffset, int length)`
- If a function needs both input and ouput parameters, should the input or output come first in the parameter list?
- Should the caller allocate an output array and pass it as a parameter (which could potentially be re-used), or should the function create and return an output array each time it is called?

The objectives are a to achieve a balance of efficiency, simplicity for API users and consistency both within the API and with established conventions.

Clearly there are a lot of options, so what is the best overall API design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So that really sounds like three questions, so here are my opinions.

Of course, this is very subjective - so - your mileage may vary:

1. Yes. Always include offset & length. If most use cases for a particular function don't
   need those parameters, overload the function so that input & length are not required.
2. For this, I would follow the standard used by `arraycopy`:

   arraycopy(Object src, int srcPos, Object dest, int destPos, int length)
3. The performance difference here is going to negligible unless the caller repeatedly calls your utility functions. If they're just one off things, there should be no difference. If they are called repeatedly than you should have the caller send you an allocated array.

Answer (score 2):

1. If you do, provide a default option too (starts at 0, full length).
2. I think most users will expect output 2nd.  However, if you might use varargs, that could change your mind.
3. I like the caller passing in the output array, but with an option for null, meaning the method will allocate.

Elaborating on the vararg comment, lets say you have a method to add two arrays.  If you put the output array arg as the 1st arg, and the 2 input arrays at the end, it is trivial to extend the method to add N arrays.

Elaborating on #3, letting callers pass in the output array, sometimes it is more efficient.  And, even if the gain is negligible, your users, dealing with primitive arrays, probably came from a C or FORTRAN background, and think the gain will be large and will complain if you don't allow them to be "efficient".  :-)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are working with arrays small enough to be allocated on the stack or in Eden, allocation is extremely fast. Therefore, there is no harm in having functions allocate their own arrays to return results. Doing this is a big win for readability.

I would suggest starting out making your functions operate on whole arrays, and introduce an option to call a function with just a slice of an array only if you find out that it is useful.

Comment: I think he is writing in Java, so the "on the stack" comment makes no sense in that context.

Comment: No, HotSpot allocates small objects that don't escape on the stack.

Comment: But since these arrays are returned as results, they definitely escape.

Comment: No, because Hotspot can inline the method call. Really, my point is just, "Do what makes the code look clean, and leave optimization to the JVM."

Comment: 95% of the time I agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

The main thing about the API design exposing multiple functions is its internal consistency. Everything else comes as a distant second.

The decision on whether or not you pass index/length pairs depends on the way the API is expected to be used. If you expect users to write series of method calls that take or put data in different segments of the same array, as in `System.arrayCopy`, then you need index/length pairs. Otherwise, it is an overkill.

Input first or output first is your decision, but once you make it, stick with it in all methods with similar signatures.

Passing output buffer is a reasonable option only if the buffer gets reused in the client. Otherwise, it's wasted effort in building and maintaining an extra set of API methods. Of course this decision is closely correlated with your choice to go with index/length pairs: if you take index and length, you should also take the output buffer.

Answer (score 1):

I think that API design is largely subjective, and/or should be heavily-influenced by the API "use-cases". What the use cases for your API, on the other hand, are entirely up to the client code.

Having said all that, personally, I would take advantage of method overloading and go for the following structure:

A method with all parameters:

`void someFunction(int[] input1, int[] input2, int offset, int length, int[] output)`

This is the main function. All other functions just call this with appropriate parameters.

`int[] someFunction(int[] input1, int[] input2, int offset, int length)`

This calls the first function, but allocates and returns the output array on behalf of the caller.

`void someFunction(int[] input1, int[] input2, int[] output)`

`int[] someFunction(int[] input1, int[] input2)`

Note that the general strategy is to make the parameter list shorter by eliminating 'optional' parameters.

In general, I tend to avoid changing method behavior depending on whether a parameter (like the output array) is `null`. It can make it harder to catch subtle errors that way. Hence my preference for two different calling styles—one where the output parameter is provided (and required), and one where the method returns its output.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `List<Double>` and have the methods return the output as a new `List`:

```
public List<Double> someFunction(List<Double> input)
```

Comment: generally good advice but not feasible in my case - for performance reasons the API has to work with primitive arrays